# finding the closest hyperplane of order $k$ in $k$ dimensional space to $N$ points

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

I have a set of $N$ points in a $k$ dimensional space, what I need to find is the closest hyperplane to those $N$ points, and I can't find a way of doing it.

*The rational:*

I want to write algorithm that does the following, for a set of $N$ points in $k$ dimensional space, where each point is a column in a matrix $X \in k\times N$ then I want to find the closest hyperplane to those points iteratively.

But I'm stuck in how given the $N$ points I find the hyperplane each time.

The equivalent of finding linear regression in a $2$ dimensional space.

Thanks.

Comment: Linear vector = vector

Comment: @Wuestenfux corrected it!

Comment: What is meant by closest hyperplane to $n$ points?

Comment: @justanothermathstudent Meaning that given a metric {$l_{1}, l_{2},..$} the sum of all points to the hyperplane is minimal; would appreciate an upvote.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. Do you mean the sum of all distances is the metric and it has to be minimum?

Comment: @justanothermathstudent no, lets say I'm using the $l_2$ norm, for each point in the space I calculate the distance of that point to the surface and sum all the distances